# Is there a status code to use when the response from server is missing a required field?

Tags: error-handling, http-status-codes, status

Say I make an API call to the server to get all information for a specific user, e.g. first name, last name, age, to display on the UI. However, when the response from server comes back, there is only last name and age available. Is there an appropriate error code to use for this missing data error? I was thinking it would be a generic 500 error since the response is incorrect. However, from the server side, there was no real error since its just a get call to the database. Is there a more appropriate error code to use for this case?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand,
API User asks for User n°XXXX and the server can't return every "required" information. It looks like a `200`, the server understood the request so far and did return what the database contains. It is api user's job to check that returned data does contain every required fields.

However, if api user doesn't provide enough informations to retrieve user then it's a `4xx` as the request is malformed and the server will not be able to retrieve data.